# Подмена данных + добавления новых в xml python

Tags: python, xml

Есть готовый xml файл, нужно создать другой с такой же структурой только менять определенные данные + еще добавить другие параметры. Как можно это реализовать, чтобы не писать всё с нуля?

Comment: https://habrahabr.ru/post/232291/

Comment: к сожалению, это не то

Comment: Приведите пример входного и выходного XML, что вы понимаете под фразой "не писать с нуля"? Точки отсчета бывают весьма различны.